# C pointer array

Tags: c, pointers

When creating a pointer array in c what does the effect of adding parentheses do?

For example

`int (*poi)[2];`

vs

`int *poi[2];`

Comment: Saves wear and tear on the keyboard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pointer to an array of 2 `int`s:

```
int (*poi)[2];
```

An array of two `int` pointers:

```
int *poi[2];
```

Normally Array has higher precedence than the pointer, but if you add the parentheses then the pointer comes "first".

Comment: .. really? [] is binding tighter I don't see why is this

Comment: @LynnYiLu - Just the way C standard is defined.

Answer (score 2):

The index operator `[]` binds stronger than the derefentiation operator `*`.

```
int *poi[2]
```

translates to:

If you see **poi**, apply `[x]` to it, then dereference the result via `*` and you get an `int`.
So it's an array of 2 pointers to int.

In

```
int (*poi)[2]
```

the parantheses force the `*` to be applied first.
So anytime **poi** is used, if you apply `*` first, and then `[x]` you get an `int`.
So it's a pointer to an array of 2 `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets bind tighter than *, so the first is an array of int pointers, while the second is a pointer to an array of ints.

Comment: You have that back to front, don't you?